# Connecting DC supply directly to a pure inductor

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, batteries, inductance

There are some controversy on the internet as far as I see about connecting DC supply directly to a pure inductor (no resistance at all in the circuit). I mean, the voltage across the inductor will eventually be zero but what about the current? Some people say that it is going to infinity as time passes, some of them say current will reach a limiting value and will be steady.

Comment: To be sure, is the DC supply ideal like the inductor? If so, there is no DC steady state solution. If the DC supply has finite short circuit current, i.e., has non-zero internal resistance, a DC steady state solution exists. There shouldn't be any controversy about this unless this distinction isn't clearly recognized. If this is what you're looking for, I will write up an answer.

Comment: So, on the internet, this distinction is also not made, but for my question I want to assume that DC supply does not have any internal resistance. I mean, the circuit does not have any resistance at all. So my question is what happens if we connect such ideal DC supply to a such ideal inductor directly without any resistance anywhere in the circuit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is straightforward in ideal circuit theory and shouldn't be controversial at all. The current through an *ideal* inductor of inductance $L$ connected (only) to an *ideal* DC voltage source with voltage across $V_{DC}$ is given by

$$i_L(t) = \frac{V_{DC}}{L}t + i_L(0)$$

This immediately follows from the equation for an ideal inductor:

$$v_L(t) = L\frac{di_L}{dt}$$

If the inductor current is finite at any time $t$, it is finite for all times $t$ but there is no DC steady state solution, i.e., the inductor current does not approach a limiting value as $t\rightarrow\infty$.

But please note that this solution is entirely non-physical. Applying ideal circuit theory usefully requires recognizing when the underlying approximations are not valid. I've mentioned this in many related answers.

Comment: Yes, this is what I also think, if we take integral of both sides, we get (ε/L)*t=i so current i goes to infinity as time passes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of visualizing Alfred Centauri's answer which might help you.

If there really is no DC resistance in the inductor and no internal impedance in the voltage source, then the steady-state solution has the current rising to infinity after the transient response (voltage drop across the inductor due to its series inductance) decays away.

As A. Centauri points out, power supplies with infinite current capability and no internal impedance do not exist (this is what he means by "non-physical") and if you tried this experiment with a real-life voltage source, it would either 1) emit some expensive smoke and noise, 2) pop its fuse or circuit breaker, or 3) detect a load error and invoke a *foldback condition* where it defaults to an internally-defined current limit so it does not emit expensive smoke or noise.

Answer (score -1):

In a perfect LC circuit, electrostatic energy converts into magnetic energy within the superconductor until exhaustion.  Then magnetic energy converts into electrostatic energy until exhaustion.

Therefore, an LC circuit is in conflict with E=1/2 Li^2.  Current from a capacitor equals volts / internal resistance.  When volts and current within the capacitor are maximum, then magnetic energy within the inductor is zero.

Therefore, DC >0 volts continuously applied to a superconductive magnet can increase magnetic energy to infinity.

Do not make the mistake of assuming a superconductive inductor acts like a series resistor.  In an LC circuit, current in a capacitor does not normally equal current in the inductor.